# Get an error when connect to azure remote desktop

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

We're using cloud service to host a MVC web application, we want to access the remote desktop to do some settings. We deploy this application by uploading the packages and configuration file. When we click on the "Connect" button on the cloud service dashboard, we got the error:

> "Failed to download the file Error details: error 400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `400 Bad Request` is a generic response when the Azure RDP configuration is bad. When I went to the [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) and tried to RDP from there I received a better explanation

> The supplied cscfg file can not be parsed. Got exception
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword

Turns out the real issue was that the thumbprint I provided for my cert did not match the cert I had uploaded to Azure. The quick fix was to

- Go to the [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) and select my cloud service
- Select the 'Configure' tab
- Select 'Remote' on the bottom bar
- Re-configure the remote desktop settings

It cycled my roles, but when they came back I was able to successfully RDP. The real fix would be to put the correct information in the Cloud Service configuration as you are deploying.